# Como raspar tabelas do QlikView usando Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

Este [site](https://paineis.cnj.jus.br/QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=qvw_l%2FPainelCNJ.qvw&host=QVS%40neodimio03&anonymous=true&sheet=shPORT63Relatorios) do governo brasileiro apresenta dados salariais para juízes de várias instâncias e tribunais. Gostaria de baixar todas as tabelas, mas os dados referentes às tabelas não estão no html que recebo como resposta quando uso `request`.

Para contornar esse problema, usei `puppeteer` e `cheerio` para abrir um navegador, esperar a tabela carregar e, em seguida, usar um seletor JQuery e extrair os dados. Este é o meu código:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");


const main = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://paineis.cnj.jus.br/QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=qvw_l%2FPainelCNJ.qvw&host=QVS%40neodimio03&anonymous=true&sheet=shPORT63Relatorios");
    await sleep(10*1000);
    const html = await page.content();
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    console.log($(".injected").text())

}

async function sleep(miliseconds) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, miliseconds));
}

main();
```

O problema é que a tabela que recebo como resposta está incompleta, com poucas linhas e células incompletas:

```
P63_CE_TRIBUNALCNJTribunalMagistradoMês/Ano Ref.CNJADHAILTON LACET CORREIA PORTO12/2018ADRIANA FRANCO MELO MACHADO02/202103/202104/2021ADRIANA LINS DE OLIVEIRA BEZERRA12/2018ADRIANO DA SILVA ARAUJO08/201909/201910/201911/201912/201901/202002/202003/202004/202005/202006/202007/202008/202009/202010/202011/202012/202001/202102/202103/202104/2021ALESSANDRA VARANDAS PAIVA MA...12/2018ALEXANDRE CHINI NETO09/201810/2018Subsídio (R$)Direitos Pessoais (1)Indenizações (2)Direitos Eventuais (3)Total de Rendimentos (4)Previdência Pública (5) (R$)Imposto de Renda (6) (R$)Descontos Diversos (7) (R$)Retenção por Teto Constitucional (8) (R$)Total de Descontos (9)Rendimento Líquido (10)Remuneração do órgão de origem (11) (R$)Diárias (12) (R$)0,000,000,00463,16463,160,000,000,000,000,00463,160,000,001.698,450,000,000,001.698,450,000,000,000,000,001.698,4533.689,110,003.639,540,0067.378,220,0071.017,760,00191,130,000,00191,1370.826,6333.689,110,003.639,540,000,000,003.639,540,00191,130,000,00191,133.448,4133.689,110,000,000,000,004.631,614.631,610,001.272,050,000,001.272,053.359,560,000,003.371,830,000,000,003.371,830,00150,970,000,00150,973.220,8632.004,710,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,719.100,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,717.700,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,711.750,005.323,940,000,002.218,317.542,250,00618,290,000,00618,296.923,9632.004,719.100,005.323,940,000,002.661,977.985,910,00594,720,000,00594,727.391,1932.004,715.600,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,714.550,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,714.550,005.323,940,0032.004,710,0037.328,650,00594,720,000,00594,7236.733,9332.004,714.550,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,710,005.323,940,004.158,850,009.482,790,00594,720,000,00594,728.888,0732.004,710,005.323,940,004.158,850,009.482,790,00673,560,000,00673,568.809,2332.004,710,005.323,940,004.158,85286,699.769,480,00673,560,000,00673,569.095,9232.004,710,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,719.100,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,714.550,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,714.550,005.323,940,000,004.436,629.760,560,001.189,440,000,001.189,448.571,1232.004,714.550,005.323,940,000,002.661,977.985,910,00594,720,000,00594,727.391,1932.004,714.550,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,714.550,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,714.550,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,714.550,000,000,000,004.631,614.631,610,001.272,050,000,001.272,053.359,560,000,003.127,300,000,000,003.127,300,00161,200,000,00161,202.966,1028.947,550,003.127,300,000,000,003.127,300,00114,300,000,00114,303.013,0028.947,5511.900,00
```

Tentei várias variações do seletor JQuery sem sucesso.

Eu li que poderia me comunicar com o QlikView usando [enigmajs](https://github.com/qlik-oss/enigma.js/) e depois fazer minha solicitação. Porém, nem mesmo o exemplo mais básico da documentação funcionou corretamente no site que estou usando.

Como faço para raspar dados de uma tabela de um QlikView?

Comment: quem negativou se importa de sugerir uma mudança na pergunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode clicar no botão `Imprimir` usando o seletor `div[title=Imprimir`. Após isso uma nova aba com os dados será aberta, basta selecionar essa aba e a função [`Page.evaluate`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v10.1.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) para buscar os dados que deseja da página. Fiz no exemplo abaixo simplesmente pegando a linha, mas como há alguns dados que são para mais de uma linha você vai precisar elaborar um pouco mais essa parte:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const aguardar = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const obterDados = () => {
  const linhas = document.querySelectorAll('table:nth-of-type(1) > tbody > tr:not(:nth-of-type(1)):not(:nth-of-type(2))'); 
  return Array.from(linhas, (linha) => {
    const colunas = linha.querySelectorAll('td:not(:nth-of-type(1))');
    return Array.from(colunas, coluna => coluna.innerText);
  });
};

const principal = async () => {
  const navegador = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const pagina = await navegador.newPage();
  await pagina.goto('https://paineis.cnj.jus.br/QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=qvw_l%2FPainelCNJ.qvw&host=QVS%40neodimio03&anonymous=true&sheet=shPORT63Relatorios');
  await aguardar(5 * 1000);
  await pagina.waitForSelector('div[title=Imprimir]', { timeout: 0 });
  await pagina.click('div[title=Imprimir]');
  await aguardar(5 * 1000);

  // Aguarda ao menos 10 segundos depois de clicar
  await Promise.all([
    pagina.waitForSelector('div.ModalDialog', { hidden: true, timeout: 0 }),
    aguardar(10 * 1000),
  ]);

  const paginas = await navegador.pages();
  const paginaRelatorio = paginas[2];
  await paginaRelatorio.bringToFront();
  await paginaRelatorio.waitForSelector('table.currentsel', { visible: true, timeout: 0 });

  const dados = await paginaRelatorio.evaluate(obterDados);
  console.log(dados);
};

principal();
```

Que resultará em algo similar a:

```
[
  [
    'ADHAILTON LACET CORREIA PORTO',
    '12/2018',
    '0,00',
    '0,00',
    '0,00',
    '463,16',
    '463,16',
    '0,00',
    '0,00',
    '0,00',
    '0,00',
    '0,00',
    '463,16',
    '0,00',
    '0,00'
  ],
  [
    '02/2021',   '1.698,45',
    '0,00',      '0,00',
    '0,00',      '1.698,45',
    '0,00',      '0,00',
    '0,00',      '0,00',
    '0,00',      '1.698,45',
    '33.689,11', '0,00'
  ],
  [
    '3.639,54',  '0,00',
    '67.378,22', '0,00',
    '71.017,76', '0,00',
    '191,13',    '0,00',
    '0,00',      '191,13',
    '70.826,63', '33.689,11',
    '0,00'
  ],
  [
    '3.639,54', '0,00',
    '0,00',     '0,00',
    '3.639,54', '0,00',
    '191,13',   '0,00',
    '0,00',     '191,13',
    '3.448,41', '33.689,11',
    '0,00'
  ],
  [
    '3.639,54', '0,00',
    '0,00',     '1.516,48',
    '5.156,02', '0,00',
    '191,13',   '0,00',
    '0,00',     '191,13',
    '4.964,89', '33.689,11',
    '0,00'
  ],
  ... XXXX more items
]
```

**Observação:** Você não precisa do `cheerio` para buscar os dados na página.

Answer (score 0):

Entrando no site que você enviou, vi que tem um ícone de Impressão, clicando nele, é gerado um link em HTML.

Acredito que de pra *parsear* tudo oq vc precisa por ele:
https://paineis.cnj.jus.br/QvAjaxZfc/QvsViewClient.aspx?public=only&size=long&host=QVS%40neodimio03&name=Temp/1ac864e398f6455cb03e8bfd1eb19cc2.html

Pelo nome do parametro: **name=Temp/** não sei se realmente é algo temporário, ai sugiro você criar uma API e não consumir diretamente do site deles.

Na sua API, captura o arquivo HTML, faz um cache e disponibiliza na sua aplicação, de tempos em tempos você atualiza sua API com o HTML de impressão gerado.

boa sorte :)